# Change the animation images of a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sdk

In my viewDidLoad method of my iPhone app I have the following code:

```
zombie[i].animationImages = zombieImages;
        zombie[i].animationDuration = 0.8/zombieSpeed[i];
        zombie[i].animationRepeatCount = -1; 
        [zombie[i] startAnimating];
```

Later on in the app the following code is called:

```
[zombie[i] stopAnimating];
                zombie[i] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"zh.png"]];
                zombie[i].animationImages = flyingZombieImages;
                zombie[i].animationDuration = 0.8/zombieSpeed[i];
                zombie[i].animationRepeatCount = -1; 
                [zombie[i] startAnimating];
```

This causes the app to crash, with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the line `zombie[i].animationImages = flyingZombieImages;`

`flyingZombieImages` is initialized with the following code: (`zombieImages` is initialized the same way)

```
NSMutableArray *flyingZombieImages = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSUInteger i=1; i <= 29; i++) {
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"flzom%d.png", i];
        [flyingZombieImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
    }
```

Why is this happening? Is there a workaround?

Comment: zombie[i].animationImages = flyingZombieImages;

Comment: How/where is flyingZombieImages initialized? Seems like that is what's causing the problem. Have you debugged to see if the array is actually valid at that point?

Comment: @dima it shouldnt matter, since he is allocating it one line above

Comment: I'm not talking about `zombie[i]`, I am talking about `flyingZombieImages`. He did not post the initialization code for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dima mentioned flyingZombieImages is likely not initialized properly, which is causing the crash. However, there is another problem as well when you create the new instances of UIImageView:

```
zombie[i] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"zh.png"]];
```

At this point you already have a reference to the old UIImageView stored in this variable. You are losing the reference to it and most likely will leak its memory. You also would want to remove the old UIImageView from the view hierarchy and add the new one.

A better way is instead to use the original UIImageView and change its image by replacing this line with:

```
zombie[i].image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"zh.png"];
```